# Xamarin Form's HttpWebRequest no timeout property?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Am using HttpWebRequest to make HTTP calls, i see it doesn't have a Timeout property ?

For example:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(aWebUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you can take a look to [James Montemagno's plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers#utils)

there is a Utils that help you to check if an async call goes in timeout. I think you can use it with your Web Request.

```
namespace MvvmHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension Utils
    /// </summary>
    public static class Utils
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Task extension to add a timeout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The task with timeout.</returns>
        /// <param name="task">Task.</param>
        /// <param name="timeoutInMilliseconds">Timeout duration in Milliseconds.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
        public async static Task<T> WithTimeout<T>(this Task<T> task, int timeoutInMilliseconds)
        {
            var retTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeoutInMilliseconds))
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (retTask is Task<T>) 
                return task.Result;

            return default(T);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Task extension to add a timeout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The task with timeout.</returns>
        /// <param name="task">Task.</param>
        /// <param name="timeout">Timeout Duration.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
        public static Task<T> WithTimeout<T>(this Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeout) =>
            WithTimeout(task, (int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds);

    }
}
```

you can find an explanation of it in this video [Channel 9 MVVM helper](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/The-Xamarin-Show-12-MVVM-Helpers)

Otherwise you can use HttpClient that has a "Timeout" property

[Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I would highly suggest working with HttpClient purely for its async Task based style. Also wanted to point out that the Task extensions mentioned above won't work with HttpWebRequest as those methods are IAsyncResult based and not Task implementations.